# Driver null while opening session in Neo4j OGM Java driver v2

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I put ogm.properties file in the same folder as class Neo4jSessionFactory. When I run my project I get information that driver is "null". What is the problem? I use Neo4j OGM driver for Java in version 2.

My session factory class:

```
public class Neo4jSessionFactory {
  private final static SessionFactory sessionFactory =
                                new SessionFactory("school.domain");
  private static final Neo4jSessionFactory factory = new Neo4jSessionFactory();

  public static Neo4jSessionFactory getInstance() {
    return factory;
  }

  public Session getNeo4jSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Driver: null
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:51)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.loadDriver(Components.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.driver(Components.java:84)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.openSession(SessionFactory.java:80)
    at neo4jCMS.Neo4jSessionFactory.getNeo4jSession(Neo4jSessionFactory.java:27)
    at neo4jCMS.Application.main(Application.java:20)
```

My ogm.properties file:

```
driver=org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver
URI=http://login:password@localhost:7474
```

Comment: What does your ogm.properties file look like?

Comment: I add this file to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put ogm.properties file in the same folder as class Neo4jSessionFactory.

The easiest way to use the `ogm.properties` is to put them at the *root of the classpath*. You don't need to put it in the same folder as the Neo4jSessionFactory or where you instantiate the factory in your app.

Comment: After moving from src/ to resources directory my problem was resolved.